# How to find infinite sum of trigonometric, hyperbolic function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, hypergeometric-function, trigonometric-series

$$u(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{-2 \cos n \pi}{n \pi}\dfrac{\sinh n \pi(y-1)}{\sinh(-n \pi)}\sin (n \pi x)$$

I tried putting random values of $x$ and $y$ and simplified. But still stuck on it. How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.se.  Please take a look at this [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to see how to write pretty math equations.  Also, please give more detail about context / what you've tried / why you think a nicer form might exist for this sum.

Comment: Three points : 1) I have converted your image into text. Check I have written properly the formula.. 2)  Did you realize that it is a Fourier series (of a odd function) with respect to variable $x$ (for a fixed value of $y$) for an odd function 3) In the front term : $\cos n\pi=(-1)^n$

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2451668